# Как не использовать asyncio.get_event_loop()

Tags: python, asyncio

Чтобы запустить асинхронную функцию в скрипте надо использовать:

```
import asyncio

async def func():
    #do something

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_untill_complete(func())
```

Есть ли способ не вызывать такую большую конструкцию?
Вызывать метод просто:

```
import asyncio

async def func():
    #do something

await func()
```

Comment: `asyncio.run(func())`

Answer (score 1):

Предпочтительный способ - `asyncio.run(func())`, или же посреди логики кода (когда цикл событий уже создан и запущен) - `asyncio.create_task(func())`.
Также вы можете заменить

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_untill_complete(func())
```

на `asyncio.new_event_loop().run_untill_complete(func())`.